# Fetch user selected Picklist value from flex card

Tags: cpq, vlocity, omnistudio, getpicklistvalues

I have picklists in flex card, where user can select Product attribute values. I am only able to see the updated value inside the flex card. I want to store the user selected value in a variable and pass that value to the API to update the attribute. Would be really helpful if someone can share their thoughts on this. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Element Name** of these picklists to directly pass as a parameter using the remote action

Let me know if this helps!!